# How to access jQuery's event handle array for object on jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, events

I know that on the firsts versions there was a `.data('events'). More recently it was put away on`$._data('events', $obj)`.

None of those seems to work on jQuery 3.3.1.

How's it working on newer versions?

Here's an example:

```
$('#tplProcesso').on('init', function (e) {
    //...
});

let test1 = $('#tplProcesso').data(events); //undefined

let test2 = $._data($('#tplProcesso'), 'events'); //undefined

let test3 = $._data($('#tplProcesso')[0].events);

jquery-3.3.1.js:4015 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery331083194960171497261' of undefined
at Data.cache (jquery-3.3.1.js:4015)
at Data.get (jquery-3.3.1.js:4066)
at Data.access (jquery-3.3.1.js:4087)
at Function._data (jquery-3.3.1.js:4237)
at <anonymous>:1:3
cache @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4015
get @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4066
access @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4087
_data @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4237
(anonymous) @ VM7170:1

let test4 = $._data($('#tplProcesso').events);

jquery-3.3.1.js:4015 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery331083194960171497261' of undefined
at Data.cache (jquery-3.3.1.js:4015)
at Data.get (jquery-3.3.1.js:4066)
at Data.access (jquery-3.3.1.js:4087)
at Function._data (jquery-3.3.1.js:4237)
at <anonymous>:1:3
```

Comment: It's not, since the question is about doing it on v3.3.1 (all mentioned solutions on that post and several others that address event handlers in jQuery won't work on the latest version - 3.3.1).

Comment: Try `$.data( element )`... Example: `$.data( $("button:first") );` I'm not sure that it is what you wish... But [this documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#jQuery-data2) mentions *«Calling jQuery.data( element ) retrieves all of the element's associated values as a JavaScript object. Note that jQuery itself uses this method to store data for internal use, such as event handlers, so do not assume that it contains only data that your own code has stored.»*

Comment: What are you using for `$obj`? It needs to be an element not jQuery object

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, this won't do it. As in the post you mentioned, what I'm trying to achieve is to access the jQuery's internal array of event handlers. That used to be on `. data()` only on the firsts versions of jQuery. Then it was on `$._data()`. Now (ver 3.3.1) is somewhere else.

Comment: @charlietfl, $obj is any result of a jQuery selection ( let's say `$('#element1')` )

Comment: I found an answer of mine that shows proper way and works in 3.3.1 (just tested it)  needs to be `$._data(domElement).events`

Comment: @charlietfl, v3.3.1 is not working with any of those.

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/axe8vpbz/

Comment: @charlietfl, you're right! Was missing the indexer `[0]` to get the DOMElement out of the jQuery selection. Many tks!